# Precharge techniques for heavy motors

Tags: inrush-current

How to prevent inrush current for a 14 Kw motor controller powered by DC source ~50-60v.

Comment: Please describe the motor, the controller and the source. And please provide a schematic.

Comment: Is this a question about motor controllers or motors?

Comment: Is about the motor controller to limit its inrush current demand during the charging stage of capacitor before actually connecting the power supply.

Comment: Yeah, some specifications are in order. 14kW @ 50VDC would equal 280A. That kind of power requires some hefty electronics.

Answer (score 1):

A stalled motor will draw more current from the same voltage than a rotating one.  There is no way around this.

You can externally limit the current, but note that this will decrease the torque.  If the motor can still start with this decreased torque, then this is a viable option to guarantee some maximum current level won't be exceeded.  If the motor requires the high *stall current* to get going, then there is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: connecting the motor controller with the motor demands a high inrush current, I used a 5W 1Ohm resistor to control the charging current for capacitor, but continuous connection dissipates much power. Is there any way to turn it off once the charging stage is completed?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the inrush is caused due to large capacitor bank. The usual methods are one power resistor and a contactor controlled by timer. At start the contactor is open and current flows trough a limiting resistor, then after a period of time the contactor closes bypassing the resistor. The auxiliary contacts can serve also as enable, since the motor controller has to be halted during precharging.

Comment: Can you suggest me the circuit to design such timing based scheme? for contactor

Comment: I have one, but it is 220VAC, but you can change the resistor values, I will try to upload somehow.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kkc7y1fk9jhqikg/InrusLimiter2.brd.pdf?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/0y6ysv8ce16bysl/InrusLimiter2.pdf?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ervdqgnmysgj9p6/InrusLimiter.brd.pdf?dl=0

Comment: Ok! I will wait for it eagerly.

Comment: But as said it's a limiter used for stepper motor drivers, where a mains transormer is used, so the circuit limits the primary current of transformer that on secondary has rectifier and large cap.